# SQL SUM on access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I currently have the following query that i wish to execute

```
SELECT Buyer.nCustomerID, Order.[Order Number], SUM(Order.[Order Total Cost])
FROM [Order] INNER JOIN [Buyer] ON Order.nCustomerID = Buyer.nCustomerID
GROUP BY Buyer.nCustomerID,Order.[Order Number];
```

However My `nCustomerID` could be duplicated so i wish to do the following:
if `nCustomerID` appears more then once, add the Order Total Cost together. I beleive that my problem is with Group By.

`Group By` should be set to just `Buyer.nCustomerID` however if i remove the `Order.[Order Number]` i Get the following error:

```
[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Order Number' as part of an aggregate function.
```

If i leave the `Order.[Order Number]` in the query then it keeps the duplicate field.

Can anyone offer any advice with this issue?

Comment: Why do you have Order Number in the query? If you only have nCustomerID in both SELECT and GROUP BY there will not be a problem.

Comment: @user1917229 I have explained that i get an error message which is above if i remove Order Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mean:

```
SELECT Buyer.nCustomerID, SUM(Order.[Order Total Cost])
FROM [Order] INNER JOIN [Buyer] ON Order.nCustomerID = Buyer.nCustomerID
GROUP BY Buyer.nCustomerID
```

It is possible that you do not need two tables.

Comment: I do need two tables as this is an ecommerse solution that already has the database structure predefined. I am just creating a java plugin to modify the data but i need to select the data first